# How to dynamically ensure that a function in an object is called only with the params that it accepts?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider the following,

```
interface ITemplateA {
    name: string;
}
const templateA = ({ name }: ITemplateA) => `Hello, I am ${name}`

interface ITemplateB {
    age: number;
}
const templateB = ({ age }: ITemplateB) => `I am, ${age} years old`;

const templates = {
    templateA,
    templateB
}

interface IGenerateText {
    template: keyof typeof templates;
    params: any;
}
const generateText = ({ template, params }: IGenerateText) => templates[template](params);
```

How can I refactor the part with `params: any`, so that typescript would pick up the following:

```
generateText({ template: 'templateA', params: { name: 'michael' } }); // no error
generateText({ template: 'templateA', params: { age: 5 } }); // error
generateText({ template: 'templateB', params: { age: 5 } }); // no error
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick. I think you could get rid of the `as any` inside the function with some cleverness too...

```
const templateA = ({ name }: { name: string }) => `Hello, I am ${name}`;

const templateB = ({ age }: { age: number }) => `I am, ${age} years old`;

const templates = {
  templateA,
  templateB,
};
type TemplateName = keyof typeof templates;

interface IGenerateText<T extends TemplateName> {
  template: T;
  params: Parameters<typeof templates[T]>[0];
}

function generateText<T extends TemplateName>({ template, params }: IGenerateText<T>) {
  return (templates[template] as any)(params);
}

generateText({ template: "templateA", params: { name: "michael" } }); // no error
generateText({ template: "templateA", params: { age: 5 } }); // error
generateText({ template: "templateB", params: { age: 5 } }); // no error
```

Comment: Try maybe `as const` after the definition of `templates` to get rid of the `as any`.

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie: interesting suggestion, would have been so great if it were enough! But sadly it is not... https://tsplay.dev/WkO3PW

Answer (score 1):

Externally (i.e. when calling the function), it is enough to have a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) (like `typeof templates` in your case, `templates` being a map/dictionary) and an inferred generic type argument selecting a key of the mapped type, to express the correlation between some of the function parameters, as done in @AKX's answer.

But internally (i.e. within the function body), this mapped type is not enough: TypeScript static analysis has no way to know that only 1 key type is used (it can still be a union of keys), hence it falls back to keeping the union of all types.

The only way to tell TS that only 1 key value is present, is to use some [type narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html). And to have TS narrow the types of correlated parameters along with it, they must be part of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions). Unfortunately, in your case this may lead to some repetitive code, which cannot be avoided currently to keep full safety:

```
type Template = keyof typeof templates;

// Build a discrimated union from the templates map:
type DiscriminatedUnionTemplates = {
    //^? { template: "templateA"; params: ITemplateA; } | { template: "templateB"; params: ITemplateB; }
    // Use a mapped type:
    [T in Template]: {
        template: T;
        params: Parameters<typeof templates[T]>[0]
    }
}[Template] // Use indexed access to convert the mapped type into a union

const generateText = <T extends DiscriminatedUnionTemplates>({ template, params }: T) => {
    // Narrow the type within the union,
    // based on the `template` discriminant key
    switch (template) {
        case 'templateA': return templates[template](params); // Okay
        case 'templateB': return templates[template](params); // Okay, repetitive but currently only way to keep full safety
    }
};

generateText({ template: 'templateA', params: { name: 'michael' } }); // Okay
generateText({ template: 'templateA', params: { age: 5 } }); // Error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'age' does not exist in type 'ITemplateA'.
generateText({ template: 'templateB', params: { age: 5 } }); // Okay
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-l+4B4E0nQgBxyAnvBYiBnsEA4JCUQWCwcAwN+CGTDa-QdgWkBFmAC4EUwqHTO+S6aqqZBKPQ6mEpecDmM++T5KRLzkQhCldkpPaqdM6lvs+2krrpij1EwACs5m8JZtwAKJQNCUBMNBsQAFYQAgqR4OeBZ4FGnHCDxzDrAgwAwJxOwgIIJ7-jg0LrFANFGjYcAgMCz71GZ3SCEaNCCKkHq-Kkgpci+-hbO+AB05C2duKmKIazkEYErnIMRHm5JEvmNP5kFWXBCFAA)

In your case, it is obvious what the function does internally, and we may accept the type assertion to avoid the repetitive code.