# Type is not correctly determined for value in key/value pair when key is narrowed down to a single property of an object

Tags: typescript, typeerror

Why can the type of `value` not correctly be determined when I narrow `key` down to a single possible property of `obj` - even though the type of `value` is the type of that property in `obj`?

```
const obj = {
    a: "FOO",
    b: 123,
}

const doSomething = <T extends keyof typeof obj>(key: T, value: typeof obj[T]) => {
    if (key === 'a') {
        value.toUpperCase();
        // Property 'toUpperCase' does not exist on type 'string | number'.
        // Property 'toUpperCase' does not exist on type 'number'.
    }
}
```

I'm assuming this might even be something that is not (yet) implemented in typescript, but I can't find any information on this problem.

**EDIT (to clarify goal further):**

I'm not trying to *use* the value of a property in `obj`. I want to set a new value which satisfies the type of a property in `obj`. And for some specific keys I want to transform the value beforehand. Something like this:

```
const setValue = <T extends keyof typeof obj>(key: T, value: typeof obj[T]) => {
    if (key === 'a') {
        value = value.toUpperCase();
    }

    obj[key] = value;
}

setValue('a', 'bar'); // {a: 'BAR', b: 123}
setValue('b', 321); // {a: 'BAR', b: 321}
```

I'm aware that this would be achievable via setters on the properties of `obj`. But at this point I don't have any control over the composition of `obj`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The approach here is similar to what *ghybs* has shown in his answer.

But there are some differences:

- The function is not generic anymore. It seems like you don't want to relate the parameter types to the return type in any way. Using a discriminated union instead of a generic type let's us avoid the narrowing issue.
- The discriminated union uses tuples instead of an object. This makes it possible to call the function like `setValue("b", 123)` without having to use an object. We can use a *rest parameter* to use the tuple as the type of the parameters and `key` and `value` can be destructured from there.

```
type ObjKeys = keyof typeof obj;

type DiscriminatedUnionObj = {
    [Key in ObjKeys]: [
        key: Key,
        value: typeof obj[Key]
    ]
}[ObjKeys]

const setValue = (...[key, value]: DiscriminatedUnionObj) => {
    if (key === 'a') {
        value.toLowerCase();
        //^? string
    } else if (key === 'b') {
        value.toExponential();
        //^? number
    }

    obj[key] = value
//  ^^^^^^^^ Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'

    setProp(obj, key, value)
}

const setProp = <T, K extends keyof T, V extends T[K]>(
    obj: T, key: K, val: V
) => obj[key] = val
```

While narrowing the type of `value` based on checking the `key` works now, we still can't do `obj[key] = value`. The compiler eagerly evaluates `obj[key]` to be a union of `string | number` which makes the assignment fail here.

But with a type-safe helper function `setProp` we can still set the value of properties.

The function `setValue` can now be called like this:

```
setValue("a", "some string")
setValue("b", 123)

setValue("a", 123)
//       ^^^^^^^^ Error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDHMCGAXDAEQBiA8ucQDTa7xECMATAMy0C+mmUAngA4BTGOSQBpQbwioYAa0kgAZjD5ClcJAG5uq4QBEAlhGAAnAwFsDYPFEEATAKpgD4UcjRZcMANoTeMKxFxSQgAXSJvOi8ceV4iP1po3AA3PAAbAFdBIl11BERfSVComGKObzc-MO5QSFgIQSgANXSsmQAKADpu71jqGFTMwXCYQ2MzS2tbR2dXJABKVAA+DBKDZXbY1BQ0AHI8XcXPJIHWwU6oEAAZEAB3QRMAYTwG9vntE5gAei+APQB+GDQMxgADmJQ4MEEaQaAQ2Wx2e3gh1Wn0GWQuIAAogAPfjgQRgKAGdJvD4nH4AmBgDLmeAPCHcLz5XpFGTowSYH44X68vm8mBYkwmEAmIgAFQEwl2wKsoN2AWkYBAsBeEAMoOs8DSwkuKilMF2YEEyQeuyZuAaUAACiL+O18v0+qchvNMFxMLVoEDGraQPwZAAecX9MRQnG2MB2aSxdQhmBNcOR6MwcW+UJLdolfISp2SeL9QZEJqYRYoFYs2KhdnpbhWlpDdrEPA0EgQEDmYSysHEN31s5N+CtlisN2YfuN5vDthu7mfGD8-mC4WiiUGo20+kmBVGakq-AQdWavDa3UgfVCQ3d+VAA)

Comment: Nice! I'll remember the tuple trick! ;-)

Comment: Cool, thank you! The tuple trick is really neat and exactly what I was looking for! The `setProp` helper function seems a bit redundant but is understandable. Can't have everything.

Answer (score 4):

As described in [How to dynamically ensure that a function in an object is called only with the params that it accepts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74885689/how-to-dynamically-ensure-that-a-function-in-an-object-is-called-only-with-the-p/74887052#74887052), while *externally* a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) (like `typeof obj` here) is enough to have TypeScript correctly detect the correlation between your 2 arguments when you call your `doSomething` function, *internally* this does not work, even after type narrowing the key.

The only way to make TypeScript infer correlated types is using a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions):

```
type ObjKeys = keyof typeof obj;

// Build a discriminated union from the obj map:
type DiscriminatedUnionObj = {
    //^? { key: "a"; value: string; } | { key: "b"; value: number; }
    // Mapped type:
    [Key in ObjKeys]: {
        key: Key;
        value: typeof obj[Key]
    }
}[ObjKeys] // Indexed access to convert the mapped type into a union

// Take parameters in a single object, possibly immediately destructured
const doSomething = <T extends DiscriminatedUnionObj>({ key, value }: T) => {
    if (key === 'a') {
        value.toLowerCase(); // Okay
        //^? string
    } else if (key === 'b') {
        value.toExponential(); // Okay
        //^? number
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, that means slightly changing your function signature (your parameters are in a single object, possibly immediately destructured).

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-HquQkymy0dylsdpggA)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Unfortunately it's not a pretty function signature to use but I guess it will do to solve this problem. I'll award the bounty and accepted answer if there isn't another surprisingly better solution popping up soon.